# Issue with Singleton bean with micronaut and vertx

Tags: vert.x, micronaut

I am running this vertx application on multi core machine (more than one verticle) and I want to create a singleton instance of PaceRedisConnection. It is creating as many as the number of verticles rather than the single instance

Source code: https://github.com/himanshumps/micronaut-vertx-issue.git

Comment: Repository deleted. I created a singleton bean of branco text and used it in verticle rather can creating a micronaut deployer for vertx verticle

Answer (score 0):

Repository deleted. I created a singleton bean of beancontext and used it in verticle rather can creating a micronaut deployer for vertx verticle